# UIView Animation isn't working

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:viewHelp cache:YES];

[self.view addSubview:viewHelp];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Where am I doing wrong? I am able to switch the view but I am not able to animate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[self.view addSubview:viewHelp];` the animation is just literally adding the subview, you need to work out what animation you want, and then apply it by changing values in the views frame property.?

follow this thread : [click me](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/13427-uiview-slide-transition.html)

Comment: The exact code was working fine in the other program where my custom class is inherited from UIView instead of UIViewController, then whats the problem, plus when i switch its orientation to landscape it works but not in portrait mode

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, i set the frame values and now its working secondly i ve changed .... `forView:viewHelp` to `forView:self.view`:)